# How can I make my haskell code work for all of the tests?

Tags: list, haskell, vector, sum

Put the vectors together in a list! Two vectors are added by adding together the same components.

```
data Vector = V Int Int Int 
vector :: [Vector] -> Vector
vector [] = (V 0 0 0)
vector [V x1 x2 x3] = (V x1 x2 x3)
vector [V x1 x2 x3, V y1 y2 y3] = (V (x1 + y1) (x2 + y2) (x3 + y3))
```

Comment: Why are you multiplying the components? Do you how to add up the elements of a list?

Comment: Hint: what does `vectorListSum (V x1 x2 x3:xs)` equal, in terms of `vectorListSum xs`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haskell do not support iteration, so you need to know how to use basic recursion or just use foldl/foldr.

```hs
vectorListSum :: [Vector3] -> Vector3
vectorListSum = foldl (\(V x1 y1 z1) (V x2 y2 z2) -> V (x1 + x2) (y1 + y2) (z1 + z2)) $ V 0 0 0
```

Every haskell tutorial will contain a same example, maybe you should read more carefully.